# Why does "12:00" converted to UTC become "11:00"?

Tags: java, jodatime

I thought `2011-10-23 12:00:00` would remain the same as `UTC` and that the `Converted date` would be **`2011-10-23 17:00:00`**.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date dt = formatter.parse("2011-10-23 12:00:00");
LocalDateTime ldt = new DateTime(dt).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
LOGGER.warn("Original date: " + ldt.toDateTime().toDate().toString());
DateTime cvtldt = ldt.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("-05:00"));
LOGGER.warn("Converted date: " + cvtldt.toLocalDateTime().toDateTime().toDate().toString());
```

I don't understand why the output is minus one hour?

```
Original date: Sun Oct 23 11:00:00 BST 2011
Converted date: Sun Oct 23 11:00:00 BST 2011
```

Comment: Daylight saving time or something? (wild guess)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `Date.toString()` which *always* uses the local time zone. See how your string contains "BST"?

Ideally, stick to *just* Joda Time for as much of the time as you can:

- Parse with the Joda Time formatters
- Don't convert back to `Date` unless you need to
- *Don't* use `Date.toString()` if you can *possibly* avoid it; you have no control over its format.

It's not clear what you're really trying to achieve, but you almost certainly don't want to do this many conversions. For example, you're calling `toLocalDateTime()` followed by `toDateTime()` again - which means it's using the system default time zone, after you'd carefully specified UTC in the previous conversion...

Your code contains the following conversions (in this order):

- String to Date
- Date to DateTime
- DateTime to DateTime in UTC
- DateTime to LocalDateTime (*)
- LocalDateTime to DateTime
- DateTime to Date
- Date to String
- (From the results at *) LocalDateTime to DateTime
- DateTime to LocalDateTime
- LocalDateTime to DateTime
- DateTime to Date
- Date to String

What do you think the chances of all those conversions being both necessary and correctly specified are? ;)

Comment: I need to store the converted date in the App Engine datastore as a `Date` object - that's why I need to convert back to a `java.util.Date` - it's the only datatype available. I'm trying to convert a client date (local timezone) to a server equivalent (always UTC).

Comment: @zippy: Right, that's fine - but you should do so with as few conversions as possible. I assume you're starting with a string - what time zone is it specified in? You should avoid *all* conversions which use the default time zone implicitly, IMO - if you want to use the default time zone, you should specify it explicitly.

Comment: Oops, you were editing your comment at the same point. You say "local time zone" - local to what? Is this the default time zone on the system your code is running on?

Comment: The client timezone is different from one user of the app to another.

Comment: I'm trying to make a rough estimation of the server equivalent datetime in UTC.

Comment: @zippy: If you don't know the client time zone, you can't possibly get the right answer. That should be your first thing to think about. Once you've got that, the rest is straightforward. Heck, you don't even really need to use Joda for this.

Answer (score 0):

Original has changed because conversion to the UTC is done with respect to HOST time zone, so it should change.

Converted had changed, in fact it's the problem of accessing method.
You are getting base time and the modifier is stored in other field.

Try going into debugging mode and you will see that after conversion cvtldt
has toString with modifier.

Regards,
Grzesiek